# Delete unwanted elements of python webscraping loop results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-cleaning

I'm currently trying to extract text and labels (Topics) from a webpage with the following code :

```
Texts = []
Topics = []

url = 'https://www.unep.org/news-and-stories/story/yes-climate-change-driving-wildfires'

response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
if response.ok:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
    txt = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'para_content_text'})
    for div in txt:
        p = div.findAll('p')
        Texts.append(p)
    print(Texts)


    top = soup.find('div', {'class': 'article_tags_topics'})
    a = top.findAll('a')
    Topics.append(a)
    print(Topics)
```

No code problem, but here is an extract of what I've obtained with the previous code :

```
    </p>, <p><strong>UNEP:</strong> And this is bad news?</p>, <p><strong>NH:</strong> This is bad news. This is bad for our health, for our wallet and for the fabric of society.</p>, <p><strong>UNEP:</strong> The world is heading towards a global average temperature that’s 3<strong>°</strong>C to 4<strong>°</strong>C higher than  it was before the industrial revolution. For many people, that might not seem like a lot. What do you say to them?</p>, <p><strong>NH:</strong> Just think about your own body. When your temperature goes up from 36.7°C (98°F) to 37.7°C (100°F), you’ll probably consider taking the day off. If it goes 1.5°C above normal, you’re staying home for sure. If you add 3°C, people who are older and have preexisting conditions –  they may die. The tolerances are just as tight for the planet.</p>]]

[[<a href="/explore-topics/forests">Forests</a>, <a href="/explore-topics/climate-change">Climate change</a>]]
```

As I'm looking for a "clean"  text result I tried to add the following code line in my loops in order to only obtain text  :

```
p = p.text
```

but I got :

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

I've also notice that for Topic result I got un unwanted URL, I would like to only obtain Forest and results (without coma between them).

Any idea of what can I add to my code to obtain clean text and topic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `p` is a `ResultSet` object. You can see this by running the following:

```
print(type(Texts[0]))
```

Output:

```
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
```

To get the actual text, you can address each item in each `ResultSet` directly:

```
for result in Texts:
    for item in result:
        print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
As wildfires sweep across the western United States, taking lives, destroying homes and blanketing the country in smoke, Niklas Hagelberg has a sobering message: this could be America’s new normal.
......
```

Or even use a list comprehension:

```
full_text = '\n'.join([item.text for result in Texts for item in result])
```

Answer (score 0):

The AttributeError means that you have a list of elements because you used `p = div.findAll('p')`.

Try:

```
p[0].text
```

or change `p = div.findAll('p')` to `p = div.find('p')` (It will only return the first case it finds)